# widget dropdown menu code

Tags: widgets, dropdown

I'm trying to put in a simple dropdown menu in my widget.  I copied one out of a previous widget and trying to substitute my own values into it.  The submenu shows, but when I click save, it saves only the first selection (design 1).  Actually, I echoed the value on the widget and all of the options displayed.

What would a simple widget drop down menu look like?
As for my code, I think I need to get that "true" out of there and replace it with Design#

```
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fold_design'); ?>"><?php _e('Display style:'); ?></label> 
        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('fold_design'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('fold_design'); ?>" class="widefat" />
            <option <?php selected( 'Design1', $instance['fold_design'], true ); ?>>Design 1</option>
            <option <?php selected( 'Design2', $instance['fold_design'], true ); ?>>Design 2</option>
            <option <?php selected( 'Design3', $instance['fold_design'], true ); ?>>Design 3</option>
            <option <?php selected( 'Design4', $instance['fold_design'], true ); ?>>Design 4</option>
            <option <?php selected( 'Design5', $instance['fold_design'], true ); ?>>Design 5</option>
            <option <?php selected( 'Design6', $instance['fold_design'], true ); ?>>Design 6</option>
            <option <?php selected( 'Design7', $instance['fold_design'], true ); ?>>Design 7</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: On a side note, this code begs for a loop to keep things [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 1):

The format of the `selected()` function you are using is incorrect.

`selected()` can only be passed two variables, you are passing three. Please see this codex article for help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected

Without you pasting more of your code I cannot see how to fix your above code.

Comment: I don't think so. If you look into the code of this function, you'll see that the 3rd parameter is "echo" which is a boolean value.

Comment: Yup you are right but the codex at the time of posting this answer the codex wasn't showing the echo parameter. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected&action=history notice the codex entry was updated in August...